# Using Redis to store word occurences

Tags: php, cache, redis

I am doing a project where I am analyzing a group of Tweets.

What I need to do is find the occurrence of each individual word. I am fairly new to Redis, so I am not quite sure that my solution is optimal. I am storing a key value pair for each word. The key is a word, and the value is the occurrence count. I then use a list to keep track of every word that goes into the cache.

```
$cache = new Redis;
$words = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if ($cache->exists($word) {
        $cache->incr($word);
    } else {
        $cache->put($word, 1);
        $cache->lpush('words', $word);
    }
}

$data = array();
$list = $cache->lrange('words', 0, -1);

foreach ($list as $word) {
    $data[$word] = $cache->get($word);
}

asort($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is alright, really. However, by your using redis, I suspect you're after a fast way to store tiny bits of data. The varname `$cache` somewhat confirms my suspicion.
If  this is the case, your using `lrange` might not be the best choice, nor is `exists` really meaningful: `INCR` creates a new key, if required, and it returns the new value of that key in every case, so you can ditch the use of `put`, and simplify your first loop to:

```
foreach ($words as $word)
{
    if ($cache->incr($word) == 1)
        $cache->lpush('words', $word);
}
```

Both these functions are atomic, so I don't think you can much improve on that.

`lrange` has a time-complexity of *O(S+N)* [according to the documentation](http://redis.io/commands/lrange). Given that you're just fetching the entire *words* collection, I'd opt for the *O(n)* alternative [`SMEMBERS`](http://redis.io/commands/smembers).
If you *are* going to use `lrange`, if you want to use pagination, for exampe, I'd consider using `SCARD` first, to determine the total number of members of your *words* collection.

Anyway, here's how I'd write the second loop:

```
$list = $cache->smembers('words');
foreach ($list as $word)
{
    $data[$word] = $cache->get($word);
}
```

I'll look into using redis itself a bit more, because it's quite easy to do away with that *words* collection, too:

```
foreach ($words as $word)
    $cache->incr($word);
$data = array();
$list = $cache->keys('*');//get all keys in collection
foreach ($list as $word)
    $data[$word] = $cache->get($word);
```

But this would imply the entire database contains nothing but words, which isn't what you want, probably. If I find the time, I'll attempt to put together a function or script that simply iterates over that *words* collection, and performs something like this

```
EVAL "return {KEYS[1], redis.call('get', KEYS[1])}" 1 <a word>
```

for each word, returning a series of redis objects that look like this:

```
1) <a word>
2) 123
```

where the 2) actually is the occurance count

*Unrelated*
I notice you're constructing an object of the `Redis` class. This, to me, tells me you're using a library *other* than [the official one](http://redis.io/clients). The `PRedis` class was, last time I checked, the preferred one. Perhaps consider changing to that lib, and see if it works for you. Anyway, look into the libs with a star next to their name :)

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks a lot!

I wasn't aware of the ->keys('*') way of fetching the words. Wouldn't i be able to use a prefix for each word and do something like ->keys('word-*')?

Btw. i am using the PRedis package, it just works under an alias in my application.

Comment: @Stromgren: Prefixing the collections would do the trick, too, I believe. Just try `$ redis-cli` and then `SELECT 1` (where 1 is the db, of course). Try the commands there.